# java error in jsp/jstl page

Tags: java, jsp, properties, jstl

I have the following code:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty sessionScope.languageRB}">
        <html:hidden property="language" value="en"/>
        <html:hidden property="country" value="GB"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise test="${not empty sessionScope.languageRB}">
        <html:hidden property="language" value="<%=languageRB.getString("style.language")%>"/>
        <html:hidden property="country" value="<%=languageRB.getString("style.country")%>"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

languageRB is an attribute stored in session, of type ResourceBundle. 
I want to do the following: if languageRB exists in session then the property is defined using the value of the string in the paranthesis, otherwise the property is set to a default value.

I'm getting the following error:

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 89 in the jsp file: /pages/common002-preparelogin.jsp
languageRB cannot be resolved

88:         <c:otherwise test="${not empty sessionScope.languageRB}">
89:             <html:hidden property="language" value="<%=languageRB.getString("style.language")%>"/>
90:             <html:hidden property="country" value="<%=languageRB.getString("style.country")%>"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried: sessionScope.languageRB.getString(..) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't mix *scriptlets* and taglibs/EL. Use the one or the other. As *scriptlets* are [officially discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202) since a decade, you should forget about them and stick to taglibs/EL. Your concrete problem is caused because *scriptltets* are always invoked regardless of outcome of JSTL taglibs. They do not run in sync with taglibs based on the coding. You can visualize it as follows: *scriptlets* run form top to bottom first and then it's taglibs/EL's turn to run from top to bottom again. You should use EL to access the resource bundle property. Additional advantage is that EL is null-safe, it won't throw a NPE, but just bypass the property access.

Secondly, you've a new problem when you replace the *scriptlet* by EL, the [`<c:otherwise>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/otherwise.html) doesn't support a `test` attribute at all. Get rid of it. It's already only hit when none of the `<c:when>` conditions have matched.

So, all with all, this should do:

```html
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty sessionScope.languageRB}">
        <html:hidden property="language" value="en"/>
        <html:hidden property="country" value="GB"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <html:hidden property="language" value="${languageRB['style.language']}"/>
        <html:hidden property="country" value="${languageRB['style.country']}"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

In expression you need to get your bundle from session directly:

```
<%=((ResourceBundle)session.getAttribute("languageRB")).getString("style.language")%>
```